# Building web app for real-time voice communication

Tags: flash, voice

My boss asked me, whether I am able to make a web app for real-time voice communication between 2 users.

I guess it should be something like server-side software + flash client.

Is there any tool available for building such an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Adobe Media Server, it is designed for handling multi user connections with streaming data/media.

http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html